# compatibility issues between Spark and Hbase when using shc core library

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am facing compatibility issues between Spark and Hbase when using shc core library. Is there any compatible shc core library or Hbase versioni can use. Below are the versions i Use

**Spark** - 2.3

**Hbase**- 1.2

**Shc-core** : shc-core-1.1.0.2.6.5.3017-2.jar

**Error**

> df = sqlContext.read.options(catalog=empdata).format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase').load()**
>
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.load.
> : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration**

Comment: can you show your dependencies (e.g. in your pom.xml or build.sbt file)?

Comment: I am using pyspark and I do not see pom.xml or build.properties file in my Hadoop or Spark or Hbase configs/ Can you help me on it?